# Sending a text file over serial port using Perl

Tags: windows, perl, scripting, serial-port

I have been writing some Perl scripts to interact with a serial port connection in the last couple days using the [Win32::SerialPort](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-SerialPort/) module. Is there a way to send a text file via the serial port? Any Perl module will do, but I would like to keep using Perl for other reasons.

Comment: You need a protocol to negotiate a file transfer on top of the raw octet streams. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kermit_protocol comes to mind, or write your own.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the old days of serial ports and POTS modems we used protocols like XMODEM, YMODEM, ZMODEM, and Kermit to transfer files over the serial connection.  I did some searching on cpan, as you would certainly not want to build the protocol yourself all over again.  The only one of those protocols (of the named ones I can remember) that seems to have CPAN support is XMODEM (which also happens to be the oldest of the ones I mentioned).

[XMODEM search on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=xmodem&mode=all)

Both ends of the line will need to support the protocol, by the way.